# localise page text with jquery

Tags: jquery, text

I have a simple 1 page website that I would like the user to be able to view in either Italian or English, depending on the language link that they choose. (I can use language headers to display correct language on page load)

I have associated id's to all span tags containing text and i'm looking for some advice on where to go from here. All of the other page functionality is developed using jQuery, so I am hoping to achieve this functionality with client-side jQuery also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this is done server-side, but I can understand how if this is a simple one-page production you might want to do it client-side. In that case, look into [jQuery localization plugins](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+localization+plugin).